# Computing function value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $g(x)= x+6$, and $h(x)=8/x$. Compute the following function value

$$(f+g)(4)$$

Can someone please help with this?? My book explains addition of functions but it doesn't say what to do if the $x$ value is defined.

Comment: By definition $f+g$ is a function defined by $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$.

Comment: If your book explains the addition of functions, then you shouldn't have a problem evaluating the function at a given value :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)=\sqrt x+x+6$, so $(f+g)(4)=\sqrt 4+4+6=12$.

Answer (score 2):

You just plug in $4$ for $x$.  So $h(4)=8/4=2$  Evaluate $f(4)$ and $g(4)$ and add them.  You could also compute $(f+g)(x)$ symbolically and then substitute in $4$.  It will get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

$(f+g)(4)$ is shorthand for $f(4)+g(4)$ So it is simply $(\sqrt4) + (4 +6)$